How to search for specific conflicting keybinding to disable it?
I use Android Studio and in this app I usually use the shortcut Shift+Cmd+] or Shift+Cmd+[ to switch between running app instances tabs.
However, when I press this keybinding I think there is another process that is consuming the binding.
I tried a shortcut detector app, and it displays the keybinding when I press it, but it keeps loading forever without showing me who consumed the shortcut.
I also searched all the keybindings in system settings but did not find this keybinding used or mentioned anywhere.
How can I know who is using it so I can disable it?
P.S.: I am on macOS Sonoma if that matters

Usually switching between apps on macOS is done with COMMAND- (that's a tilde). And as it is something built into macOS it is difficult to change. I have heard that Karabiner Elements can do this but have not tried it myself. If the COMMAND- does switch windows hopefully that helps narrow down what you need to do to change it.

@SteveChambers I am not having problems with Cmd+Tilde, I am having problem with SHIFT+Cmd+] key binding, it is being consumed somewhere before android studio can consume it - this is my problem.

Ah I see where the confusion came from, by saying "running app instances tabs", I don't mean instances of android studio, but rather instances of the current android app (Flutter app) running on multiple devices, where each instance has a corresponding tab inside the IDE's window (which is only one window)

Yes Shift Cmd [ switches between tabs normally in Sonoma e.g. in Safari Numbers. However you description of Android Studio seems odd and confusing - as the multiple devices and saying instances of app are just confusing. - anyway does the key work with Safari?

@mmmmmm yes they work in safari, could this be the app consuming them (and if yes how to disable them)? (safari was not opened when I was working in Android Studio)
